# To retrieve data from a CSV file, split it and store data of one column in a string array without duplicates

Tags: java, csv

condition 1 : the csv file is like

```
abi^siri^ram^ravi
abc^^cde^ram,siri^ravi
```

In some rows the tokens are like `^^`  (its not null ,and there is no space in between) 
I have to retrieve the 3rd coloumn into a string array, but am unable to understand how to handle `^^` cases.

condition 2 : as shown in 2nd row one tuple i.e (ram,siri) it should again be splited and should be stored in the same array.

condition 3 : the string array should not contain duplicates.

my program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Parser{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:\\myfile.csv");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fs);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = null;

    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String[] values = line.split("\\^");
        String reqcol = values[values.length - 1];
        System.out.println(reqcol);
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to retrieve the column but unable to handle `^^` cases

Comment: http://www.jfilehelpers.com/index_en.php

Comment: Why you do not replace all '^^' with '^' ?
like
`line = line.replace(/^^/g,"^");`

Comment: If he replaces ^^ with ^, he loses information -- the ^^ tells him he has a column without a value, and if he just replaces it with ^ he loses the column entirely.

Answer (score 1):

String.split() is not appropriate for your conditions.  Ditch it.

It isn't going to be that hard to search for the next occurrence of a delimiter starting from a position in the string; do that repeatedly (using String.indexOf(delimiter, start)) to find each field and load up your own list (I would use ArrayList, convert to array at the end if I have to have an array).

There is a bit of futzing to make sure you have the starting and ending positions correct, but that's part of what programming is about.  It will allow you to detect the ^^ cases and enter an empty or null string at your preference.  Sorry, brute force is going to be easier to do than manhandling something that does not handle your cases so that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling your own thing for such a generic task as working with CSV files is not needed in 99% of cases. Most of basic issues like empty values or values which contain your delimiter inside are handled out-of-the-box by most of libraries. You can start with [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/index.html) and [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). I've used SuperCSV in my project, it performs well and also very easy to learn.

When you read CSV row (so library API deals with all parse hassles), you may then get value for column #3, parse it with String.split() and put this to Set collection to ensure elements are unique.